# What does this circuit symbol mean? (Circle with horizontal line through it)

Tags: current, identification, diagram

I came across the following symbol in a [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2113a.pdf) (functional block diagram on page 8).  What does it mean?

[image: circuit symbol circle with horizontal line view 1]

[image: circuit symbol circle with horizontal line view 2]

For future searchers, the symbol is a circle with a horizontal line (diameter) through it.

Does it just indicate that the current through the branch has a particular value? A current limit? Something else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a fixed **current source** (DIN 40700 style). With an arrow pointing to it an externally controlled current source. In this case it's a CCCS (Current Controlled Current Source), where the generated current is the controlling current divided by 500, resp. 1000, depending on the device.

Other common current source symbols include:

[image]

[image]

Controlled current sources may be indicated by:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was familiar with the other two symbols, but not this one. I take it DIN 40700 is a German standard of some kind?

Comment: @David - Yes, "Deutsche Industrie Norm". Most DIN standards have been superseded by European standards ("ENxxxx"). If you look around you'll find more symbols for current sources, but I think these are the most common ones. *"The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from."* -- Andrew S. Tanenbaum.