# Can you name this schematic symbol?

Tags: schematics

What does this schematic symbol mean?

[image]

Comment: Also related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/what-does-this-circuit-symbol-mean-circle-with-horizontal-line-through-it

Answer (score 2):

This is a current source symbol.

It provides a constant current (whose value should be written next to the symbol), whatever the voltage across it. And basically, it's the opposite of a constant voltage source (ideal power supply).

Its meaning is not different from the usual symbol with a single circle.

Here are different symbols for current source:
[image]
<sup>Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ideal_current_source_symbols.svg</sup>

They all mean the same.

- *a* is the usual US symbol.
- *b* is a variant of *a*.
- *c* is the DIN40700 symbol (german).
- *d* is the usual european symbol.
- *e* never saw that one before today, actually.

Your specific symbol is actually a mix of *a* and *d*. Half-US, half-european. A "melting pot" symbol, somehow.

Comment: How does this differ from a single circle with an arrow in it?

Comment: Why do you think it should differ? Just another convention

Comment: It differs by having **two** circles!